# JSF Float Conversion

Tags: jsf, exception, floating-point, converters

I'm using JSF 1.2 with IceFaces 1.8 in a project here.

I have a page which is basically a big edit grid for a whole bunch of floating-point number fields. This is implemented with `inputText` fields on the page pointing at a value object with primitive `float` types

Now, as a new requirement sees some of the fields be nullable, I wanted to change the value object to use `Float` objects rather than primitive types. I didn't think I'd need to do anything to the page to accomodate this.

However, when I make the change I get the following error:

> /pages/page.xhtml @79,14 value="#{row.targetValue}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

And

> /pages/page.xhtml @79,14 value="#{row.targetValue}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@1449aa1

The page looks like this:

```
<ice:inputText value="#{row.targetValue}" size="4">
  <f:convertNumber pattern="###.#" />
</ice:inputText>
```

I've also tried adding in `<f:convert convertId="javax.faces.Float" />` in there as well but that doesn't seem to work either! Neither does changing the value object types to `Double`.

I'm sure I'm probably missing something really simple but I've been staring at this for a while now and no answers are immediately obvious!

Comment: Can't reproduce this with Mojarra 2.0.2 on Tomcat 6.0.20 (without IceFaces). Can you please post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @BalusC Unfortunately I don't have access to the full stack trace, the error is generated within JSF and I don't have access to it. But I am working on some more info, bear with me for a minute...

Comment: Just get it from server logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation (see e.g. [here](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/64-fconvertnumber-tag-in-jsf.html), [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/200601.mbox/%3C20060120130851.4017510FB0A6@asf.osuosl.org%3E) and [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=510663)) that `<f:convertNumber>` is the problem. It seems that the number it converts to is dependent on the input you give it - it could be an integer or a floating point number. In other words, it doesn't look at the target type - it just generates an instance of java.lang.Number. Which is hardly ideal, although I can't determine whether this is because somewhere I'm using an old version of JSF or EL or something like that.

There seem to be three solutions:

1. Use `java.lang.Number` as your value object type;
2. Write your own converter;
3. Don't use `<f:convertNumber>`.

Unfortunately #1 isn't an option for me for other reasons, and I don't want to write my own converter at the moment. However if I change the code to remove the convertNumber, everything seems to work OK. (I've also updated the value object type to `Double` which was suggested in one of the links I looked at).

That prevents the exceptions, and it looks like JSF is still doing what I want it to do. Just annoying that it seems you can't specify `convertNumber` and the convert type in the same instance.

Comment: the number converter, in myfaces at least uses `DecimalFormat` to parse the value, so that's the ideal way.